# How to iterate an array of Objects based on the level of iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, recursion

I generate an array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
      "key":"e34b50a9c1ec",
      "value":"VALUE",
      "level":1,
      "childs":[
         {
            "key":"c870e48ea94e",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[
               {
                  "key":"004188f853ee",
                  "value":"VALUE",
                  "level":3,
                  "childs":[

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "key":"0fb2a55700b0",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"c9aede8a9fc8",
      "value":"VALUE",
      "level":1,
      "childs":[
         {
            "key":"b32a88f21ac3",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[
               {
                  "key":"bbabbc6563ff",
                  "value":"VALUE",
                  "level":3,
                  "childs":[

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "key":"6e103fc9340e",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And i have a varible that contains the current level of the object, for example:

```
let currentLevel = 1
```

And depending on the level of the currentLevel variable I want to obtain the **keys** of only that level of the object. For example:

```
let currentLevel = 2
```

With this I would get the following keys:

```
[c870e48ea94e, 0fb2a55700b0, b32a88f21ac3, 6e103fc9340e]
```

I had thought to use a recursive function but the truth is that I am not sure how to build it. any idea how to do it?

Comment: Is it nesting of objects, or arrays, or both to be considered?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov just nesting of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (be aware that no checks is performed):

```js
let arr = [
   {
      "key":"e34b50a9c1ec",
      "value":"VALUE",
      "level":1,
      "childs":[
         {
            "key":"c870e48ea94e",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[
               {
                  "key":"004188f853ee",
                  "value":"VALUE",
                  "level":3,
                  "childs":[

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "key":"0fb2a55700b0",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"c9aede8a9fc8",
      "value":"VALUE",
      "level":1,
      "childs":[
         {
            "key":"b32a88f21ac3",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[
               {
                  "key":"bbabbc6563ff",
                  "value":"VALUE",
                  "level":3,
                  "childs":[

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "key":"6e103fc9340e",
            "value":"VALUE",
            "level":2,
            "childs":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
const getChildsKey = (arr, depth) => {
    if(!depth) return null;
    if(depth == 1)
        return arr.map(el => el.key)
    else
        return arr.flatMap( o => getChildsKey(o.childs, depth-1))
}
console.log(getChildsKey(arr, 2))
```

Comment: I just implemented it in my code and it works perfectly, just what I needed, thanks :)